# Show the active parent menuitem on hover in bootstrap dropdpwn menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a simple 2 level dropdown nav in bootsrap with the code below:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
      <li><a href="/" title="Főoldal" class="top_menu_to_link">Főoldal</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" title="Iskolánk" class="top_menu_to_link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Iskolánk</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/alapadatok" title="Alapadatok" class="submenu_link">Alapadatok</a></li>
            <li><a href="/" title="Még egy teszt menü" class="submenu_link">Még egy teszt menü</a></li>
            <li><a href="/osztalyok" title="Osztályok" class="submenu_link">Osztályok</a></li>
            <li><a href="/" title="Teszt menüpont valami" class="submenu_link">Teszt menüpont valami</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" title="Információk" class="top_menu_to_link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Információk</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/" title="Teszt, infók menüpontba" class="submenu_link">Teszt, infók menüpontba</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/arlista" title="Árlista" class="top_menu_to_link">Árlista</a></li>
      <li><a href="/hirek" title="Hírek" class="top_menu_to_link">Hírek</a></li>
      <li><a href="/kepgaleria" title="Képgaléria" class="top_menu_to_link">Képgaléria</a></li>
      <li><a href="/dokumentumok" title="Dokumentumok" class="top_menu_to_link">Dokumentumok</a></li>
      <li><a href="/kapcsolatfelvetel" title="Kapcsolatfelvétel" class="top_menu_to_link">Kapcsolatfelvétel</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I added this css to the style file, because i want to show the submenu on hover, not clicking a nav item.

```
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0; 
 }
```

When i click the "iskolánk" nav item, and move the cursor to the submenu, the "Iskolánk" nav item will get a white background, that shows me, that this is the active item, and also shows the submenu.

If i dont click the "Iskolánk" nav item, only just hover it, the submenu shows up, but if i move the cursor to the submenu, the "Iskolánk" nav item looses the white background, and it doesnt show that that is the active nav item.

How can i do that? I want to show the submenus always on hover, and not by clicking the parent. The bootstrap css and js file is from the bootstrap website, i dont change anything in them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you are moving to the submenu, cursor leaves the menu (parent) so the CSS hover does not work on it. So to solve this you can write a simple jquery code which keeps the hover effect on the parent(menu) when you are moving to the submenu. but remember, when you are leaving that submenu, you have to remove that effect from the parent.

Add this code snippet to your HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.dropdown-menu').hover(function(){
         $(this).parent().css({background:'#eee'});
      })
      $('.dropdown-menu').mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).parent().css({background:'#fff'});
      })
   })
</script>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you, i will write back soon when i ckecked, but i think, it will work.